# Использование C# dll из "С"

Tags: c, .net, com, dll

Собственно вопрос уже в названии. Прошу обратить внимание, что использовать нужно именно и С. Из плюсов это взаимодействие более-менее прозрачно. Единственное, на что наталкивался в ходе поисков, так это привлечение [COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c3fd4a20.aspx). Но не разобрался как с этим работать. Так что хотелось бы найти несколько дельных советов в этом направлении. Доступ к исходникам dll есть.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Использование объектно-ориентированного кода из функционального - это любопытно. Можно поинтересоваться, почему DLL должна быть именно .net сборкой, а использовать ее нужно именно из сишного кода?

Comment: [Здесь](http://cppkid.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-unmanaged-code/) есть простой пример по загрузке managed dll из unmanaged c++ с использованием COM-интерфейса.

Comment: Да, очень любопытно. Но используется не по этому. Скажу так, Си я не выбирал - это необходимость. А С# упрощает реализацию неких процессов в десятки раз. Вот здесь и родилось... Конечно, все таки мысли реализовать все в Си подбираются все ближе и ближе :-)

Comment: > Скажу так, Си я не выбирал - это необходимость

Что мешает писать на C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Кроме COM'a нет нормальных вариантов для interop'a вида C# -> C, поэтому вам придется разобраться с ним.
- Если вкратце, то сначала вы объявляете в вашем C# коде [некоторый COM Interface,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa645736) и реализовываете его в managed коде как [`ComVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute) класс.
- После этого необходимо в C коде создать определение **этого же** интерфейса, которое должно выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
      BEGIN_INTERFACE

      HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *QueryInterface )( 
          IMyComInterfaceImplementedInDotNet * This,
          /* [in] */ __RPC__in REFIID riid,
          /* [iid_is][out] */ 
          __RPC__deref_out  void **ppvObject);

      ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *AddRef )( 
          IMyComInterfaceImplementedInDotNet * This);

      ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *Release )( 
          IMyComInterfaceImplementedInDotNet * This);

      // ...
  } IMyComInterfaceImplementedInDotNetVtbl;

  interface IMyComInterfaceImplementedInDotNet 
  {
      CONST_VTBL struct IMyComInterfaceImplementedInDotNetVtbl *lpVtbl;
  };
  ```
- Далее, протащить managed объект в C код можно путем соответствующего вызова [`CoCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686615) — после этого вы сможете совершать действия над полученным объектом типа `'IMyComInterfaceImplementedInDotNet *'.`

> Разумеется, тут есть куча подводных камней, касающихся маршаллинга параметров, времени жизни объектов и прочих, которые, к сожалению, просто не влезут в этот ответ `:)`

- Вообще, лично на мой взгляд, сделав шаг в сторону [C++ / CLI,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) который хорошо выполняет роль прокладки между .NET и C / Unmanaged C++, можно сэкономить кучу времени при организации Interop'a.

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже уже думал на счет "прокладки из С++". Посмотрим что можно сделать!